# Spring RowMapper

Tags: java, spring

In Spring and Hibernate, when I use a Custom RowMapper, it throws the following error

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.nxsol.hospital.DAO.ReportsHibernateDAO$PRCRowMapper.<init>(Lcom/nxsol/hospital/DAO/ReportsHibernateDAO;Lcom/nxsol/hospital/DAO/ReportsHibernateDAO$PRCRowMapper;)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a different runtime version of Spring and/or Hibernate than what you have during compilation. I'd suggest you start solving the problem by comparing jar libraries.

Comment: I have same lib both runtime and compilation. How can i check whether jars are mismatched. I am using eclipse, in Build path i have some set of jar file.and war file build by ant with with same class path. This created war file deployed in tocmat.